# What's the best way to mix passport-facebook and passport-jwt?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, mean-stack, jwt, passport-facebook

I am kind of new to Node.js development and currently working on a pet project on my free time.

So far I have created JWT authentication using [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) and [passport-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt) for the strategy and I am using it in all of my RESTful APIs.

Now I am thinking of mixing this with some sort of Facebook authentication still want to stick with token authentication.

Currently this is how I am generating and obtaining the token:

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(400).send(getErrorMessage(err));

        if (!user) {
            res.status(400).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'
            });
        } else {
            if (user.checkPassword(req.body.password)) {

                let token = jwt.encode(user, config.secretPhrase);

                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    token: 'JWT ' + token
                });
            } else {
                res.status(401).send({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'
                });
            }
        }
    });
};

app.route('/api/users/authenticate')
        .post(user.authenticate);
```

And to validate I do the following:

```
let user = require('../../app/controllers/user-controller');
app.route('/api/todos')
        .get(user.validateLogin, todos.list)
        .post(user.validateLogin, todos.create);
```

user-controller:

```
exports.validateLogin = passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
});
```

Anyone can suggest a neat way to mix the two strategies ? should I use [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) ? What's the difference between express-jwt and passport-jwt ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) like what you did with `passport-jwt` with new strategy so you can save Facebook user token in your database and return your token

Comment: This is the most common approach. You can implement multiple passport strategies for auth, and return your jwt on success. Would be a new auth route, if user has an account already and logs in w/ fb, look for the email in DB, if it exists then send your user the jwt.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if currently you're sending back the token to the end user. How are you saving that client side? I'd recommend using a simple JWT library like jsonwebtoken, and setting the token as an httpOnly cookie. If you're currently saving it in localStorage you might be more vulnerable to an XSS attack.
Here is a gist with how I am currently handling setting and checking a JWT for a user:
https://gist.github.com/briancw/8c2021817c3bd34972e8e8deb6048a4f

Answer (score 0):

You can first use the passport-jwt auth strategy, then inside the passport-facebook strategy pass to super() the argument `passReqToCallback: true` and add `request` as first parameter of your `validate` function, inside that function you can now combine the facebook oauth response and the `req.user` coming from your the passport-jwt strategy.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Profile, Strategy } from 'passport-facebook';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/commons/services/prisma.service';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class FacebookStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'facebook') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      // ...
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
  }

  async validate(
    req: Request, // add this param
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done: (err: any, user: any, info?: any) => void,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const payload = {
      profile,
      accessToken,
      user: req.user, //combine strategies here
    };

    done(null, payload); // payload will be available as req.user
  }
}
```